# Google Cloud SQL not updating with script

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

I have a long script which is designed to edit a specific row in the Cloud SQL table. The code is long so i will shorten it.

Client Side:

```
function build_profile(){
var cbid = sessionStorage.getItem("client_id");
var self = this;
var createSuccess = function(data){
  var statuse = ["Active", "Wiating", "Discharged"];
  if(data !== false){
    data = data.split(",");
    var dec = app.pages.Profile.descendants;
    dec.fname.text = data[1];
    dec.sname.text = data[3];
    sessionStorage.setItem("school_id", data[9]);
    app.popups.Loading.visible = false;
  }
  };
var init = function() {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createSuccess).get_user_data(cbid);};
app.popups.Loading.visible = true;
init();
}

function save_profile() {
var createSuccess = function(data){
var dec = app.pages.Profile.descendants;
console.log(data);
if(data !== -1){
  var ds = app.datasources.Clients;
  ds.load(function(){
    ds.selectIndex(data);
    console.log("editing:"+ds.item.CBID);
    ds.item.fname = dec.fname_edit.value;
    ds.item.sname = dec.sname_edit.value;
    ds.load(function(){build_profile();});
  });
}
}};
var init = function() {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createSuccess).update_client(sessionStorage.getItem("client_id"));};
init();
}
```

Server Side:

```
function get_user_data(cbid){
try{
var query = app.models.Clients.newQuery();
query.filters.CBID._equals = parseInt(cbid);
var results = query.run();
if(results.length > 0){
  var arr = [
    results[0].Id, //0
    results[0].fname, //1
    results[0].sname //3
      ];
    return arr.join(",");
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  }catch(e){
  console.error(e);
  console.log("function get_user_data");
  return false;
  }
}
function update_client(cbid) {
  try{
    var ds = app.models.Clients;
    var query = ds.newQuery();
    query.filters.CBID._equals = parseInt(cbid);
    var results = query.run();
    if(results.length > 0){
      var id = results[0]._key;
      return id+1;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

This gets the Clients table and updates the row for the selected client, then rebuilds the profile with the new information.

EDIT: I have managed to get to a point where its telling me that i cannot run the query (ds.load()) while processing its results. There does not seem to be a manual check to see if it has processed?

Note: datasource.saveChanges() does not work as it saves automatically.

Comment: What does the Google SQL Logs say? Is it possible the query is timing out? How long does this query take/

Comment: If you could clarify how either of the client functions are called? Is this via a button click on the client? Looking at your code I think you have an issue with how async functions are called using google apps script. You might want to consider splitting your build_profile and it's success function apart and do the same with the save_profile function also. Also, your server functions don't need the try/catch, if your server script encounters an error it will automatically log it in the console and you can furthermore throw your own error if the query returns nothing.

Comment: There is no set way the code is called in my applications, it happens on page load, then on a button press, and a few times just as other functions complete. The code i posted is 1 of about 30 functions all with the same issue. There is no issues with the Errors or the way i handle them. the script is expecting a return value so i always make sure to have one and deal with it. I have come across a solution myself after some testing and it does not require timeouts or waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You error is being produced by the client side function **save_profile()** and it is exactly in this block:

```
  ds.load(function(){
    ds.selectIndex(data);
    console.log("editing:"+ds.item.CBID);
    ds.item.fname = dec.fname_edit.value;
    ds.item.sname = dec.sname_edit.value;
    ds.load(function(){build_profile();});
  });
```

So what you are doing is reloading the datasource almost immediately before it finishes loading hence you are getting that error

> cannot run the query (ds.load()) while processing its results

This is just a matter of timing. A **setTimeout** can take of the issue. Just do the following:

```
ds.load(function(){
  ds.selectIndex(data);
  console.log("editing:"+ds.item.CBID);
  ds.item.fname = dec.fname_edit.value;
  ds.item.sname = dec.sname_edit.value;
  setTimeout(function(){
      ds.load(function(){build_profile();});
  },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to find a solution to this particular issue. It requires **Manual Saving** but it saves a lot of hassle as one of the inbuilt solutions can be used rather than relying on dealing with errors or timeouts.

```
function client_query_and_result(){
  var createSuccess = function(data){ //callback function
    console.log(data);
  };
  app.datasources.SomeTable.saveChanges(function(){//ensures all changes have been saved
    app.datasources.SomeTable.load(function(){//makes sure to reload the datasource
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createSuccess).server_query_and_result(); //at this point All data has been saved and reloaded
    });
  });
}
```

The Server side code is the exact same methods. To enable manual saving you can select the table in App Maker -> Datasources -> check "Manual save mode".

Hope this can be useful to someone else.